# Install terminator on macbook as terminal emulator

Tags: macos, gnome-terminal, terminator

I got a brand new macbook m1 chips, I am trying to use terminal emulator `terminator` there, i have installed it with `brew install terminator` but i don't see it's in installed app and search it, i dont find it anywhere in my machine.

is it really possible to use `terminator` on macbook? how can i do it? can anyone help me?

I am tried a a lot but coundt found any solution even on google

```
brew install terminator 

Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> New Casks
soothe2
==> Updated Casks
Updated 3 casks.

Warning: terminator 2.1.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 2.1.1, run:
  brew reinstall terminator
```

this is the terminal screen as proof that i have installed terminator but i dont see in installed app page and search using `command+space`, not result too

Answer (score 9):

Ciao anamul, I think you should be able to start Terminator by typing `terminator` in the normal macOS Terminal.app

In general I suggest you try [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/), it might give you a better experience on macOS compared to Terminator.